# Eiffel: local declaration in or and and failed to compile

Tags: compiler-errors, eiffel

The compiler is complaining about an unknown identifier, seems that it does not recognize any of my multiple declarations, where am I wrong?

```
if attached {INTEGER_REF} field.item as l_int
        or attached {INTEGER_64} field.item as l_int
        or ( attached {TUPLE} field.item as l_tuple and then attached {INTEGER_64} l_tuple.item (1) as l_int ) then
    Result.put_integer (l_int.to_integer_64, primary_key_db_column_name)
elseif attached {STRING} field.item as l_s then
    Result.put_string (l_s, primary_key_db_column_name)
end
```

[image]

### Update

As this seems a valid expression I thought that if in every branch of my **or** a `l_int` is declared I should be able to use it in the **then** scope.

But it seems that this expression **is valid**

```
if attached a.b as l_b and then attached l_b.c as l_c then
    l_c.is_available_in_this_scope
    l_b.is_available_in_this_scope
else
    io.putstring ("you are wrong dear and either l_b and l_c are not available!")
end
```

While this one **not!**

```
if attached a.b as l_b and then attached l_b.c as l_c
        or attached a.x as l_b and then attached l_x.d as l_c then
    l_c.is_available_in_this_scope -- Compiler complain about l_c
    l_b.is_available_in_this_scope -- Compiler complain about l_b
else
    io.putstring ("you are wrong dear and either l_b and l_c are not available!")
end
```

### With my code

This **compiles**

```
    if attached {INTEGER_REF} field.item as l_int then
        Result.put_integer (l_int.to_integer_64, primary_key_db_column_name)
    elseif attached {INTEGER_64} field.item as l_int then
        Result.put_integer (l_int, primary_key_db_column_name)
    elseif attached {TUPLE} field.item as l_tuple and then attached {INTEGER_64} l_tuple.item (1) as l_int then
        Result.put_integer (l_int, primary_key_db_column_name)
    elseif attached {STRING} field.item as l_s then
        Result.put_string (l_s, primary_key_db_column_name)
    else
        logger.write_error ("to_json-> Type not found in matching:" + field.item.out)
        check
            not_found_item_type: False
        end
    end
```

While this **not**

```
if attached {INTEGER_REF} field.item as l_int then
    Result.put_integer (l_int.to_integer_64, primary_key_db_column_name)
elseif attached {INTEGER_64} field.item as l_int
        or attached {TUPLE} field.item as l_tuple and then attached {INTEGER_64} l_tuple.item (1) as l_int then
    Result.put_integer (l_int, primary_key_db_column_name) -- Unknown identifier `l_int`
elseif attached {STRING} field.item as l_s then
    Result.put_string (l_s, primary_key_db_column_name)
else
    logger.write_error ("to_json-> Type not found in matching:" + field.item.out)
    check
        not_found_item_type: False
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object tests have scopes. Denoting an object test with `OT`, its scope for

```
if OT         then A else B end
if OT and ... then A else B end
if OT or  ... then C else B end
```

is only `A`. Therefore, for a disjunction, the scope is empty, and you cannot use the corresponding object test local in any of the branches.

If there are two object tests in a conditional, their scopes may overlap or not:

```
if OT1 and      OT2 then A else B end
if OT1 and then OT2 then A else B end
if OT1 or       OT2 then C else B end
```

Here, as before, the object test local variable of `OT1` has a scope `A`. In addition, for `and then`, the scope includes `OT2`, in particular, `OT2` can use the local of `OT1`. For the same reason, `OT2` cannot use the same object test local of `OT1`.

For the disjunction, scopes of object test locals of both `OT1` and `OT2` are empty. To be more informative, the same code with mnemonic names looks like:

```
if attached e1 as x and      attached e2_without_x as y then use_x_and_y else B end
if attached e1 as x and then attached e2_with_x    as y then use_x_and_y else B end
if attached e1 as x or       attached e2_without_x as y then no_x_no_y   else B end
```

It would be still possible to rewrite the example with just one first branch **if the type of the all involved expressions is the same** (that is not the case, because there are types `INTEGER_64` and `INTEGER_REF`):

```
if attached
       if attached {INTEGER_64_REF} field.item as i then
           i
       elseif
           attached {TUPLE} field.item as t and then
           t.count > 0 and then
           attached {INTEGER_64_REF} t.item (1) as i
       then
           i
       else
           Void
       end
   as j
then
   -- Use j
...
```

but this becomes too cumbersome, and using multiple branches or temporary local variables looks like a better alternative.

Comment: Many thx, that helped me but I did an edit on my question because there is still a doubt for me in this case... is the compiler complaining here because `l_int` could be either a INTEGER_REF and a INTEGER_64?

Comment: @Pipo It's because for disjunction the scope of an object test local variable is empty. And, every object test is considered separately, i.e. two object test locals cannot be treated as a single one. So, for disjunction you have two empty scopes, and cannot use either variable.

Comment: Sorry, even reading you about 10 times I still miss the point :-( did you see my edit? maybe you could add an edit to your answer if you have the motivation!

Comment: @Pipo There is no rule that combines object test local variables from two object tests into a single variable. Moreover, the scope of an object test local variable is empty if the object test is used in a disjunction. I've updated the answer with more examples.

Comment: Got it this time!!! The `or` and INTEGER_64/INTEGER_REF made it unavailable which makes sense Now not for compilation restriction but my mistake Maaaaany thx!!

Answer (score 0):

Well for a start you can't use the same identifier (l_int) for multiple object test locals in the same scope.

Comment: Thx, but thats what I did no? what would be my case with your advice?

Comment: see my edit and question to Alexander for more precision, thx!